# Firestore publicly writable collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

When a user is created I need to add some additional data about the user (e.g. name).

So I need a publicly writable collection. However I've tried adding `create` and `update` (I think that's for `set` and `add` respectively), but I'm still getting  "Error: Missing or insufficient permissions." when trying to do:

```
db.collection('newUsers').add({
  firstName,
  lastName,
});
```

With this rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /newUsers {
      allow create, update;
    }
  }
}
```

How can I add an entry to that collection without being authed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /newUsers/{user} {
      allow create, update if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you need to match an actual document, not just a collection.  The wildcard `{user}` should do this.

Comment: Aha thanks! FYI it seems the `if true` part is superfluous but maybe more descriptive

Comment: Yes, I like to always have a condition in place that makes it perfectly clear under what circumstances the rule should take effect.  It's actually not too uncommon.